# How to get data of memo app on Samsung phone?

Tags: android

- I am a newbie. I try to get data(content, title ....) of memo app on Samsung phone. I used to `"content://com.samsung.android.memo"`. My app is crashed and show message

  java.lang.SecurityException: Permission Denial: opening provider com.samsung.android.app.memo.model.provider.memo.MemoProvider from ProcessRecord{9d45db 22489:com.example.kenshin.internetsamsung/u0a199} (pid=22489, uid=10199) requires com.samsung.android.memo.READ or com.samsung.android.memo.WRITE
- After I add uses-permission on `AndroidManifest.xml`.  but it still crashed. Please give me a advice. Thanks

  "uses-permission android:name="com.samsung.android.memo.WRITE" and
   "uses-permission android:name="com.samsung.android.memo.READ"

  ```js
  final Uri uri = Uri.parse("content://com.samsung.android.memo");
  final Cursor c = getContentResolver().query(uri, null, null, null, null);
  ```

Comment: See if Samsung offers an official API for this. It is entirely possible that this provider and its permissions are only for use by Samsung's own apps, not third party apps.

Comment: If I root my phone, I can query data of Memo app but it is not good method. The SmartSwitch app can do it. I want to build a app same as SmartSwitch app. Do you have any method can do it? Thanks.

Comment: Again, see if Samsung offers an official API for this: http://developer.samsung.com